# Auto-scroll content with selected item

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scrollview

I have a dropdown menu, which is working fine using a mouse or touch:

[image]

But, I would like to also allow the keyboard or joystick to control it.

I can select the dropdown items and navigate, you can notice the fourth item is selected ("Atlantis" in red).

But, if I go down to the next item bellow it--using only keyboard for example--the content doesn't scroll down automatically.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solve this way

```
if (Input.blablablagetbuttondown)
{
    TemplateViewPortContentRectTransform.anchoredPosition += new Vector2(0,
    TemplateViewPortContentItemRectTransform.sizeDelta.y);
}
```

With some name changes to explain better what are the objetcs... And equivalent code to go up.